# React Native & Amplify - Build Command

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

Going through my first React Native / Amplify setup, and I noticed something that I can't find an answer to.

Amplify asks for a single build command during initialization (`amplify init`).

```
? Build Command: (npx run-script build)
```

It suggests `npm run-script build`, but react-native (v 0.63.4 - the latest at this time) does not ship with a build command.

The prebuilt scripts are:

```
"scripts": {
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "react-native start",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
}
```

So, what should I put for the single build command? Does react-native have a generic web build? What makes the most sense for the amplify deployment?

Sorry if this comes off as a noob question...

Comment: Looks like an undocumented feature. I found that those configurations go in the /src/amplify/.config/project-config.json. If we edit "StartCommand": "dir", and run "amplify run" on Windows, it will execute the "dir" command. So it looks like support commands to use the amplify CLI to build and run our projects. For now I just let them as empty strings.